# iOS - Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I know questions like this have been asked on here before but they are not really related to the same problem. First of all I am very new to Swift and Xcode. So, I am creating a simple notes app and the error I am trying to come across is the one that is highlighted in the image attached to this question. The error is this one for the ones who can't view the image: `"Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)".`

I am at a point where I am trying to get the `prepareForSegue` function but I do not know what is causing this error as I do not understand it. Could someone people help or advise on how I could fix this error. Many thanks in advance.

[image: Error is highlighted in red!]

Comment: try debugging to see what is causing the problem, navigationItem might be nil

Comment: or, (in addition to luk2302 comment) the index `self.selectedIndex` present an index that does not exist for the object `arrNotes` (i.e. out of bounds). Try some "manual" debugging, e.g. writing out the index to console (`print("\(self.selectedIndex)")`)

Comment: @luk2302, `navigationItem` can't be `nil`.  It isn't optional, and it is created the first time the property is accessed.

Comment: @vacawama even before the view is loaded? Was not sure about it - does not change the rest of the statement regarding OP: debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that `NotesViewController` do have the `UINavigationController` embedded at that. Because that property refers to the existing `navigationItem` from `UINavigationController`. Otherwise, that line will return `nil` and that's the reason why it crashes.

If you don't want to embed an `UINavigationController`, you can just drag and drop Navigation Bar to make one in the Storyboard.